PLS analysis does not produce any results?
I've recently installed SPSS 29 to run a PLS analysis on some human sample data. This data consists of multiple continuous independent variables and 4 independent ones: sex, patient group, type of epithelia studied and age. All string variables I've converted to numbers (that's to say: 1 for male and 2 for female).
I have followed the IBM tutorial and installed Python, numPy and Scipy and downloaded the PLS extention.
When I try to run the PLS analysis, the program indicates that it is indeed running but does not produce any result (the output window does not open at all; no error is displayed). This does not happen for any other type of analysis I've run or any other command.
I've installed and uninstalled SPSS, python... all the components multiple times but I cannot get the PLS analysis to run.
Is there something I am missing that is preventing the program from giving me an output?
Thank you very much.

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
